# Matlab KeyPressFcn with zooming

Tags: matlab, zooming, matlab-figure

Basically i just want to get some points coordinates on image using getpts function. The idea was to use zoom (at the panel) to find target region at the image and then invoke getpts on keypress and specify a point.
I have installed keypress callback

```
fig_h = figure;
set(fig_h,'KeyPressFcn','keypress');
hold on;
imshow(b);
```

This callback works fine just before i start zooming. But after i have zoomed some region it stops calling my callback. How can i achieve expected behaviour? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a lazy workaround which does the job:

Basically create a pushbutton whose callback executes the same as the `KeyPressFcn` in your code. That is, whenever you press the button the function `getpts` is executed, even if you are in zoom mode. Then you don't need to press any key to activate the function but rather press a button:

```
function  KeyPress(~)
clc
clear

%// Test image
b = imread('peppers.png');

fig_h = figure('Position',[200 200 500 500],'Units','Pixel');

%// Create pushbutton and define its callback
hButton = uicontrol('style','push','Position',[20 20 60 30],'String','Get Points','Callback',@(s,e) keypressCB)

hold on;
imshow(b);

    function keypressCB       
        [x, y] = getpts(fig_h) 
    end

end
```

Screenshot after zooming, with `getpts` enabled:

[image]

Hope that helps!